# Is there a limit to the size of a formula in a chart series collection in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel

I have a VBA macro that constructs a series formula from cell values in worksheets and plots the data by FY quarters. It has been working seamlessly for years until now.

I expanded the x-axis from 4 quarters to 12 and the series for building the x-axis crashes with a run time 1004 error. It works if I build the series manually using the same values from the series formula string.

It also works if I run only 11 quarters of data. It is not data related because I can change the date ranges to earlier dates and the 11 quarters still works. So, it covers the entire range of the 12 quarters in different charts.

The only difference is the length of the string used to build the formula. however, the string that fails is shorter than the one that is in the series that preceded it.

I put code in to write the series string to a file do I could look for problems.

Here is a sample of the output that crashes. The number at the end of the row is the character count:

```
"=SERIES('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$C$52,Constants!$M$7:$N$18,('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$52,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$66,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$73,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$80,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$87,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$101,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$108,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$115,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$122,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$136,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$143,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$150),1) 390"
"=SERIES('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$C$53,Constants!$M$7:$N$18,('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$53,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$67,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$74,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$81,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$88,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$102,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$109,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$116,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$123,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$137,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$144,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$151),2) 390"
"=SERIES('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$C$54,Constants!$M$7:$N$18,('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$54,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$68,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$75,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$82,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$89,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$103,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$110,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$117,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$124,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$138,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$145,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$152),3) 390"
"=SERIES('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$C$55,Constants!$M$7:$N$18,('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$55,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$69,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$76,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$83,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$90,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$104,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$111,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$118,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$125,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$139,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$146,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$153),4) 390"
"=SERIES('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$C$56,Constants!$M$7:$N$18,('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$56,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$70,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$77,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$84,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$91,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$105,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$112,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$119,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$126,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$140,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$147,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$154),5) 390"
"=SERIES('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$C$57,Constants!$M$7:$N$18,('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$57,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$71,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$78,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$85,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$92,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$106,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$113,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$120,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$127,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$141,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$148,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$155),6) 390"
"=SERIES("Qtrly Average",Constants!$M$7:$N$18,('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$58,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$72,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$79,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$86,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$93,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$107,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$114,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$121,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$128,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$142,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$149,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$156),7) 380"
```

Here's the same series using 11 quarters that works:

```
"=SERIES('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$C$52,Constants!$M$7:$N$17,('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$52,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$66,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$73,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$80,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$87,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$101,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$108,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$115,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$122,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$136,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$143),1) 362"
"=SERIES('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$C$53,Constants!$M$7:$N$17,('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$53,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$67,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$74,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$81,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$88,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$102,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$109,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$116,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$123,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$137,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$144),2) 362"
"=SERIES('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$C$54,Constants!$M$7:$N$17,('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$54,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$68,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$75,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$82,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$89,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$103,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$110,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$117,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$124,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$138,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$145),3) 362"
"=SERIES('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$C$55,Constants!$M$7:$N$17,('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$55,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$69,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$76,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$83,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$90,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$104,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$111,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$118,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$125,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$139,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$146),4) 362"
"=SERIES('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$C$56,Constants!$M$7:$N$17,('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$56,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$70,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$77,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$84,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$91,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$105,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$112,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$119,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$126,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$140,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$147),5) 362"
"=SERIES('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$C$57,Constants!$M$7:$N$17,('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$57,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$71,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$78,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$85,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$92,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$106,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$113,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$120,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$127,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$141,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$148),6) 362"
"=SERIES("Qtrly Average",Constants!$M$7:$N$17,('QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$58,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$72,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$79,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$86,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$93,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$107,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$114,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$121,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$128,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$142,'QTRLY-ANNUAL DATA'!$AO$149),7) 352"
```

I apologize for the amount of territory this has consumed, but I have beat my head until it is soft over this one.

Comment: There may be issues with the maximum number of arguments the SERIES function can handle. To verify, try hardcoding the values. This will also provide a minimum working example wich answerers can base their answers on. Maximum formula length was 1024 way back then, so that's probably not it.  --- EDIT Here are the official linitations: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3 none of the ones I skimmed seem to apply... Still, maybe SERIES is special.